# Jpa subclass mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I am making a POS like system. I wonder how to map subclass using JPA (this is for my DAO). `Product` class has product details and `OrderProduct` class has information about the `Product` and details about the order.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO
    public int getId(){ return id;}

    /**
     Other get/set methods
    */
}

@Entity
@Table(name="order_products")
public class OrderProduct extends Product{
        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        public int getId(){ return id;}

        /**
         Other get/set methods
        */
}
```

I got complain about duplicate `@Id`. But `OrderProduct` class really need another id than the product one. How should I map this?

DB is something like this

```
Table products
id int
name varchar(32)

Table order_product
id int
quantity int
productid int fk referencing product table
```

Would `@IdClass` or `@AttributeOverride` help?

Comment: The DB schema you have provided indicates a ManyToOne relationship between OrderProduct and Product, so it's not a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you'd like to achieve is possible neither with JPA nor Hibernate. When using a joined subclass strategy, the PK of the subclass is the the PK of the base class and is used to perform the join between the tables. From the JPA specification:

> #### 2.1.10.3 Joined Subclass Strategy
>
> In the joined subclass strategy, the
>   root of the class hierarchy is
>   represented by a single table. **Each
>   subclass is represented by a separate
>   table that contains those fields that
>   are specific to the subclass** (not
>   inherited from its superclass), **as
>   well as the column(s) that represent
>   its primary key. The primary key
>   column(s) of the subclass table serves
>   as a foreign key to the primary key of
>   the superclass table**.

You could use a `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` to change the column name in the child class:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
public class OrderProductTop extends ProductTop {
    ...
}
```

But `PRODUCT_ID` would still be the PK.

And to be honest, I don't understand your physical model. To me, what you currently have represented is a one-to-many relationship, which is not correct (it should be a one-to-one).